# Java UI Layout Issues

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

I am trying to create a crisp Java UI layout for a stand alone application. I know that JSwing is not the best UI, but it is what I have right now.

My UI currently looks like:
[image]

I want the text lined up, the buttons lined, up and the submit and status under all of them, stacked or parallel to each other.

My layout is currently like this:

```
        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    layout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(lbl_inputFile)
        .addComponent(txt_inputFile)
        .addComponent(btn_inputFile)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(lbl_searchTermFile)
                .addComponent(txt_searchTermFile)
                .addComponent(btn_searchTermFile))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(lbl_outputFile)
                .addComponent(txt_outputFile)
                .addComponent(btn_outputFile))
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(btn_sumbit)
        .addComponent(lbl_status))
    );

    layout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, btn_inputFile, btn_outputFile, btn_searchTermFile);

    layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(lbl_inputFile)
                    .addComponent(txt_inputFile)
                    .addComponent(btn_inputFile))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lbl_searchTermFile)
                    .addComponent(txt_searchTermFile)
                    .addComponent(btn_searchTermFile))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lbl_outputFile)
                    .addComponent(txt_outputFile)
                    .addComponent(btn_outputFile))
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btn_sumbit)
                    .addComponent(lbl_status))
    );
```

Any ideas how to fulfill what I want?

Comment: Take a look at the [Oracle Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MigLayout layout manager from http://www.miglayout.com/
From this site you can download jar file miglayout-4.0-swing.jar for Swing, make it available in your projects classpath.
To give you an idea about how the layout manager works, below is the source code for the Quick Start

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
panel.add(firstNameLabel);
panel.add(firstNameTextField);
panel.add(lastNameLabel,"gap unrelated");
panel.add(lastNameTextField,"wrap");
panel.add(addressLabel);
panel.add(addressTextField,"span, grow");
```

Above code produces following panel
[image]
If you are using eclipse, then u can use WindowBuilder plugin by Google ( http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php ). Its a GUI form designer also supports Swing and specially it contains build in support for MigLayout layout manager.
Following is screen shot of WindowBuilder open in eclipse
[image]

Comment: Thank you, WindowBuilder has been great!